# Can't send email to my own domain

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, sendmail

I've set up sendmail on my ubuntu server and I have the following PHP code set up to email my own domain `contact@example.com`:

```
$subject = "Hello!";
$message = "This is a test.";

$header = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail("contact@example.com", $subject, $message, $header);
```

However, the email never arrives. However, when I change the destination email to Gmail or Yahoo, the email sends just fine.

This is the output of my `mail.log` file:

```
Oct 24 16:41:17 CA2EXAMPLE01 sendmail[4476]: s9OGfHVe004476: from=www-data, size=186, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201410241641.s9OGfHVe004476@CA2EXAMPLE01.example.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Oct 24 16:41:17 CA2EXAMPLE01 sm-mta[4477]: s9OGfHeD004477: from=<www-data@CA2EXAMPLE01.example.com>, size=431, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201410241641.s9OGfHVe004476@CA2EXAMPLE01.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Oct 24 16:41:17 CA2EXAMPLE01 sendmail[4476]: s9OGfHVe004476: to=contact@example.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30186, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s9OGfHeD004477 Message accepted for delivery)
Oct 24 16:41:17 CA2EXAMPLE01 sm-mta[4479]: s9OGfHeD004477: to=<contact@example.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@CA2EXAMPLE01.example.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120431, relay=mail.example.com. [11.23.41.55], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by mail.example.com.
```

The main issue I see in the error log is `Deferred: Connection refused by mail.example.com`, but I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: `\r\n` is for windows

Comment: @meda I don't think that explains my issue since I can send the emails fine to a gmail account but not to my own domain.

Comment: I didnt say that is the reason, just pointing this out, but you should make sure sendemail service is running and go check the logs

Comment: @meda sendmail is definitely running (I'm able to send mail to gmail accounts) and I pasted the errors from the log in my post.

Comment: `Connection refused` always has to do with network, you need to check firewall, because gmail uses diifferent ports

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for in my firewall?

Comment: You should be allowing port 25 at least for smtp, gmail can use 587 sometimes, if you know how to use wireshark you can watch the ports that fail to connect

Comment: My server shows that it's listening on port 25: http://i.imgur.com/RHI6hF9.png

Comment: did you associate you `127.0.0.1` to your hostname `mail.example.com`

Comment: I have the following set in `/etc/hosts`: http://i.imgur.com/jqIktnt.png

Answer (score 1):

you need to change config of postfix

```
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and remove your domain name from `mydestination`'s value

Comment: I don't have postfix installed, only sendmail.

Comment: @user4171336 i think it must help you http://serverfault.com/a/128450 it is the same thing what for postfix ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry for the loopback ip:

```
#add this to bind hostname
127.0.0.1      CA2EXAMPLE01.example.com//whatever you meant by mail.example.com
```